# Outline non-convex polygon in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, polygon

I'm trying to draw an outlined non-convex polygon in OpenGL, but I'm being unsuccessful, hence the question.
What I'm doing, basically, is tessellate the polygon and create a Display List from that. Then I draw it twice, once filled, then just the lines. So this is the code I have, so far:

```
GLUtriangulatorObj *tess = gluNewTess();

gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_BEGIN, (void (__stdcall*)(void))tessBeginCB);
gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_END, (void (__stdcall*)(void))tessEndCB);
gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_ERROR, (void (__stdcall*)(void))tessErrorCB);
gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_VERTEX, (void (__stdcall*)())tessVertexCB);

GLuint poly = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(poly, GL_COMPILE);

gluTessBeginPolygon(tess, NULL);
gluTessBeginContour(tess);

// calls to gluTessVertex(tess, v, v); to add vertices

gluTessEndContour(tess);
gluTessEndPolygon(tess);
gluDeleteTess(tess);

glEndList();


// DRAW
glPolygonOffset(1.0, 1.0);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
glCallList(poly);
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
glCallList(poly);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

Obviously, I get the outlined polygon plus all the inner lines.
So how do I remove those inner lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the triangles filled as you do now, but draw the outline without breaking the polygon apart.

Comment: Pretty obvious. But seems to work fine. Thanks. I thought there would be some more "advanced" way of doing it, but sometimes simpler solutions are better.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the polygon in black.  Then draw the polygon again, normally, with a small z-offset and slightly smaller.  You'll have a black outline.

Edit:  Actually you are specifying the outline of the polygon as a set of gluTessVertex calls.  So just render those vertices as a GL_LINE_STRIP.